# If a (real-valued) function is $o(x^k)$ near $x=0$, must it be $k$ times differentiable?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

If a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is $o(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$, then it follows trivially that $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$.

Analogously, suppose a function $f$ is $o(x^k)$ as $x\to 0$, where $k$ is a positive integer. (That is, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/x^k = 0$.) In this case, **if $f$ is $k$ times differentiable at the origin**, I can deduce that $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = \cdots = f^{(k)}(0) = 0$. Is the $o(x^k)$ condition strong enough to show that these first $k$ derivatives actually exist? If so, how? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Play with $\sin \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: What about $f(x) = |x|^3 $ times the characteristic function of the rationals? – It is only differentiable at $x=0$, so $f''$ does nowhere exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is assumed to have derivatives up to order $k$ in a neighborhood
of $x=0$ then $f(x) = o(x^k)$ implies
$$
 f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = \ldots = f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \, .
$$
This follows for example from [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_one_real_variable)
$$
 f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2} x^2 + \ldots + \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k
 + h_k(x) x^k 
$$
with $\lim_{x \to 0} h_k(x) = 0$.

But for $k \ge 2$, $f(x) = o(x^k)$ does not imply the existence of 
$f^{(k)}(0)$, a counter-example is 
$$
 f(x) = |x|^{k+1}  \text{ times the characteristic function of the rationals}
$$
which is *only* differentiable at $x=0$, so that $f''$ nowhere exists.